# How to do an XOR of the binary forms of all integer items in a list

Tags: python, list, xor

I have a list of the form `[1,2,3]`. I want to do a list XOR of the binary form of this list i.e. 
`01 XOR 10 XOR 11 = 0`. How do I do this in one step?

(Yes I have gone through SO, havent found something that is working for me)

Comment: yikes, yes its the same. Vote to close

Answer (score 6):

You can use Python's built-in [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function and the [`operator` module's `xor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.xor) to do this in one step:

```
>>> reduce(op.xor, [1, 2, 3])
0
```